# Unable to convert String to Date by requestBody in spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, serialization

I have the below Code :

**DTO :**

```
 Class MyDTO {
        import java.util.Date;
        private Date dateOfBirth;

        public Date getDateOfBirth() {
                return dateOfBirth;
            }
        public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
                this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
            }

    }
```

**Controller**

```
public void saveDOB(@RequestBody MyDTO myDTO, HttpServletRequest httprequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
       System.out.println("Inside Controller");
       System.out.println(myDTO.getDateOfBirth()); 
}
```

**JSON Request :**

```
{
"dateOfBirth":"2014-09-04",

}
```

**If I send the request as yyyy-mm-dd automatic conversion to date object happens.**
**output in controller:-**
dateOfBirth= Thu Sep 04 05:30:00 IST 2014

**But when I send DateofBirth in dd-mm-yyyy format It does not convert String to Date automatically.So how i can i handle this case.**

**JSON Request :**

```
{
"dateOfBirth":"04-09-2014",

}
```

**Output:** No Output in console does not even reaches controller.

I have tried with @DateTimeFormat but its not working.

I am using Spring 4.02 Please suggest is there any annotation we can use.

Comment: have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505997/passing-a-date-as-json-with-spring-mvc-and-jackson

Answer (score 14):

`@DateTimeFormat` is for form backing (command) objects. Your JSON is processed (by default) by Jackson's `ObjectMapper` in Spring's `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` (assuming the latest version of Jackson). This `ObjectMapper` has a number of default date formats it can handle. It seems `yyyy-mm-dd` is one of them, but `dd-mm-yyyy` is not.

You'll need to register your own date format with a `ObjectMapper` and register that `ObjectMapper` with the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`. Here are various ways to do that :

- [Configuring ObjectMapper in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854030/configurating-objectmapper-in-spring)
- [Spring, Jackson and Customization (e.g. CustomDeserializer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591291/spring-jackson-and-customization-e-g-customdeserializer)

Alternatively, you can use a `JsonDeserializer` on either your whole class or one of its fields (the date). Examples in the link below

- [Right way to write JSON deserializer in Spring or extend it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376304/right-way-to-write-json-deserializer-in-spring-or-extend-it)
- [How to deserialize JS date using Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591967/jackson-date-deserialization)

Answer (score 2):

List itemCreate a class to extend `JsonDeserializer`

```
public class CustomJsonDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        String date = jsonParser.getText();
        try {
            return format.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Use `@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomJsonDateDeserializer.class)` annotation on `setter` methods.

Thanks `@Varun Achar` answer, [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591967/how-to-deserialize-js-date-using-jackson)